# Binary to Decimal (mathematics way)

Tags: python, binary, decimal

If there is an binary number:10011100
It is 156 in decimal.

I want to use mathematics way to make binary to decimal.

For example:
binary: 10011100

the first number is 1:  `2**7`
the forth number is 1:  `2**4`
the fifth number is 1:  `2**3`
the sixth number is 1:  `2**2`

then `2**7+2**4+2**3+2**2 = 156`

I think, I need to use string.find() method.

```
>>> my_str = '10011100'   
>>> my_str = my_str[::-1]   
>>> print(my_str)   
00111001   
>>> my_str.find('1')   
2   
>>>
```

I just can find the first '1'.

How to find all the index of '1'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you want to retrieve the indexes? You can simply iterate over the bits like this:

```
num = sum(2**i for i, bit in enumerate(my_str) if bit == '1')
```

Anyway, you can get the indexes like this if you prefer two separate steps:

```
indexes = [i for i, bit in enumerate(my_str) if bit == '1']
num = sum(2**i for i in indexes)
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `my_str[::-1]`, i.e. shouldn't you iterate in reverse order?

Comment: @stephan: Well the OP already does `my_str = my_str[::-1]` .. but without that you are right.

Answer (score 1):

You may also check the built-in `int()` function that takes a base argument:

```
int(x[, base]) -> integer
```

---

```
In [1]: my_str = '10011100'

In [2]: int(my_str,2)
Out[2]: 156
```

Comment: It work. But, It isn't a mathematics way to figure out this problem.

Comment: @user2011210 -- I agree, but I thought it could be useful for others, who may stumble across this question in the future...

Answer (score 0):

**Binary Number:**
If you are considering why binary number has a base 2 always well the answer is a binary number is expressed in the base-2 because it uses only two symbols: typically "0" (zero) and "1" (one). eg 10011100 (only "zero" and "one" used)

---

If there is an binary number:10011100 It is 156 in decimal.
The *Binary number here* is 10011100 it always has a base 2 even if it is not written **10011100** *is same as* **10011100 base 2**

**Convert Binary to Decimal**

- We start from the most right number and move toward left

  - Multi the binary number with 2 that is the base and the power(^) keeps increasing by 1

    (0*2^0)+(0*2^1)+(1*2^2)+(1*2^3)+(1*2^4)+(0*2^5)+(0*2^6)+(1*2^7)

    =156

---

If you want to under stand more clearly here is a link 
[https://www.mathwarehouse.com/non-decimal-bases/convert-binary-to-decimal.php?ref=driverlayer.com][1]